# Retrieve Folder Name of Last Folder in Directory

Tags: vba, excel, directory

I am working on automating the saving procedure of our purchase orders that we do through an Excel workbook. Instead of the user having to copy the template into the correct directory and renaming it with the correct order number that’s next in the sequence along with the date (for e.g. the previous order was order number SJ-K1880 placed on the 7th July 2016 with filename KO_SJ-K1880_070716, so the next order number would be SJ-K1881 placed on the 11th of July 2016 with filename KO_SJ-K1881_110716), the user only needs to click a Save button and it will save the workbook in the correct directory under the right filename automatically following the sequence. Here’s an example of the full directory of one such file:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Kyocera Order Doc\
Kyocera Orders\Orders 2016\07 July 2016\
KO SJ-K1880 070716\KO_SJ-K1880_070716.xlsm
```

Using the current date I have managed to check the existence of the directory up until `07 July 2016` and create it if it doesn’t exist. My problem comes in finding the last folder from that directory (which is `KO SJ-K1880 070716` in this example) and using it to determine what the next order number is going to be.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to give you what you want but it relies on an ascending sort of the folder names.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim fldr As String

    fldr = Environ("USERPROFILE") & _
        "\Desktop\Kyocera Order Doc\Kyocera Orders\Orders 2016\07 July 2016"

    Debug.Print mostRecentFolderNdx(fldr)
End Sub

Function mostRecentFolderNdx(base As String)
    Dim f As String, lstndx As String

    f = Dir(base & "\*", vbDirectory)
    Do While CBool(Len(f))
        If Not CBool(InStr(1, f, Chr(46))) Then
            lstndx = Split(f, Chr(32))(UBound(Split(f, Chr(32))))
        End If
        f = Dir
    Loop

    mostRecentFolderNdx = lstndx
End Function
```

If you are going to rely on an ascending sort order, it is better to have your folders use a naming convention like `\20160707\` rather than `\07 July 2016\`.

Comment: O yea, I should probably have mentioned that the 07 in “07 July 2016” refers to the month number so that the folders in that directory can sort according to months. I.e. the other folders in that directory are “01 January 2016”, 02 February 2016”, ect. … “07 July 2016”. Does this change anything?

Comment: Yes, it seems that should be sufficient to maintain a reliable ascending name sort order.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeeped. Would you mind maybe adding some comments explaining your code?

Comment: What part of it are you having trouble with (and isn't covered adequately by official documentation)?

Comment: Well, unfortunately Jeeped, when run the program seems to get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: That **is** unfortunate. I had recreated your directory structure on my laptop (even added a few dummy folders) and it worked as expected. Since debugging would require access to the directory structure on your machine I would suggest stepping through the procedure and function with [F8] while setting Watches.